# Is it possible to fire a call for multiples of 3 in typeahead.js

Tags: typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

[typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) jQuery plugin fires call for every letter or we can give the **minLength** for suggestions rendering. I want to show the suggestions only for multiples of 3

Answer (score 1):

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

```
$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 3
            },
                {
                    name: 'items',
                    source: substringMatcher(items)
                });
```

Comment: @Preethy  jsfiddle.net/kblau237/y468t3pg/23 is a live link - just change the minLength